# How to programmatically unwrap weth

Tags: python, arbitrum

I di d a swap using uniswap exactInputSingle from Link to WETH. But I am stuck unwrapping WETH now. I used to use the function withdraw, but for some reason, I do not find that function in the '0x82aF49447D8a07e3bd95BD0d56f35241523fBab1' contract.
Any idea how I could please?